# DatePicker does not exist in the namespace in windows phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8

When i run my application it works fine but the design page giving error "Invalid Markup" and 
The name "DatePicker" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit".

Answer (score 1):

i think your spelling mistake `assembly`

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

Comment: When i run my application it works fine but when i stop the debugging,design page giving error "Invalid Markup" .